# Static variables as cache possible issues

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a scenario with below use case:

1. The function `someFunctionToGetValue` takes around 10 seconds to process.
2. api is called ~300 requests per second.
3. The data of this api is same for all users.
4. The data changes rarely.

To handle the throughput I have used static variables as cache which refreshes every 10 minutes.

```
import javax.ws.rs.PATH;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Path("/home")
@Singleton
class MyResource {

     private static String value;   //this is actually a complex huge pojo

     @Get
     public Response getConfigData(){

           boolean isMinsLapsed=Calender.getInstance().get(Calender.Minute)%10==0;

           if(value==null || isMinsLapsed){
               value=someFunctionToGetValue();
           }
           return value;
     }
}
```

This code needs to be sent to production and wondering on the below points.

1. Drawbacks of using static variables as cache in above scenario?
2. Any better ways of API caching with eviction in place?

Comment: If you have a way to "invalidate" the cache - that is, if you somehow know if the result would change, then there might be better ways to do this.

Comment: `boolean isMinsLapsed=Calender.getInstance().get(Calender.Minute)%10==0` if request rate is 300 rps, that will cause 18000 requests every 10 minutes run without cache.

Comment: With this request one request every 10 minutes will have to pay the price for the API call. Instead, you could schedule the API call in the background as appropriate and update the cached value when the call returns. This way you still get roughly the same maximum age of the value and none of the service calls will have to take 10 seconds longer.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a race condition between two calls, the first call queries the `value` which is null, while performing the heavy `someFunctionToGetValue` the second call will still see `value` as null.

This might not be an issue for you, but if you want to make sure the value is only calculated once you can use memoization with expiration (like Guava's)

```
Supplier<String> memoizedSupplier = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
  CostlySupplier::generateBigNumber, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Additionally, since the resource is a singleton, the value argument does not need to be static because it is only instantiated once.